# How to truncate log in this scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I have faced below the scenario.

[image]

checkpoint run is getting failed.
DB is in the simple recovery model, unable to shrink the file, getting attached error
The log file is enabled for autogrowth, drive having a good amount of free space.
 When we tried to add space in the log file, getting attached error.
We tried to run DBCC update usage and SP_resetstattus got attached error.

Please let me know is there any fix? without restart the SQL server and  rebuild the logfile.

Comment: HI Srinivasulu. Please take some time to include the actual error message *in writing* to your question. Images cannot be searched or indexed for text.

Comment: Is option maxsize set on ldf file?

Comment: And which sql server edition was installed?

Comment: HI Alexander, SQL server version is 2012 SP2
the log file is enabled for autogrowth and max size is 2TB.

Comment: You mentioned a version, but not an edition... Is this an express edition?

Comment: its enterprise edition

Answer (score 1):

According to OP, the version of the data engine is SQL Server 2012 SP2

- In case of the express edition:

  - Maximum relational database size - 10 GB ([Editions and supported features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017))
- If the edition is other than express:

  - Is there any disk space quotas on a storage level?
  - Something prevents LDF shrinking. To be checked via: `SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc, recovery_model_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '<Name>'`
  - [FIX: Database does not follow simple recovery model behavior in SQL Server 2012 after you set the recovery model of the "model" database to "Simple"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2830400/fix-database-does-not-follow-simple-recovery-model-behavior-in-sql-ser)

The workaround for the bug mentioned above:

```
ALTER DATABASE <Name> SET RECOVERY FULL;
ALTER DATABASE <Name> SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
USE <Name>
DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 128)
```

And as the last resort, to make database operational, add another transaction log file:

```
ALTER DATABASE <Name>
ADD LOG FILE 
(  
    NAME = DB_log_2,  
    FILENAME = 'Full_Path\DB_log2.ldf',  
    SIZE = 128MB,  
    MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED ,  
    FILEGROWTH = 64MB  
);
```

After performing necessary log shrinks that new file eventually can be removed because:

- [Multiple log files and why they’re bad](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/multiple-log-files-and-why-theyre-bad/)